# After establishing TCP connection with server, why can't I see message sent from server?

Tags: java, sockets, tcp, tcpclient, wifi-direct

I have made an app that should connect to a sensor via WiFi Direct, then connect to port 5001 on the sensor to get the sensor data.

I have used "Simple Socket Tester" to start a server on another phone to see if my app succeeded in connecting to port 5001 on that server. When connected, I can send messages to the server, which is displayed on the other phone.  But when I send messages to the client from the other phone, I am not receiving the message in my app.

Why is that? Am I missing something inside my code?

```
public class TCPClient {

    public static final String SERVER_IP = "192.168.1.52"; //your computer IP address
    public static final int SERVER_PORT = 5001;

    // message to send to the server
    private String mServerMessage;

    // sends message received notifications
    private OnMessageReceived mMessageListener = null;

    // while this is true, the server will continue running
    private boolean mRun = false;

    // used to send messages
    private PrintWriter mBufferOut;

    // used to read messages from the server
    private BufferedReader mBufferIn;

    /**
     * Constructor of the class. OnMessagedReceived listens for the messages received from server
     */
    public TCPClient(OnMessageReceived listener) {
        mMessageListener = listener;
    }

    /**
     * Sends the message entered by client to the server
     *
     * @param message text entered by client
     */
    public void sendMessage(String message) {
        if (mBufferOut != null && !mBufferOut.checkError()) {
            mBufferOut.println(message);
            mBufferOut.flush();
        }
    }

    /**
     * Close the connection and release the members
     */
    public void stopClient() {

        // send mesage that we are closing the connection
        /*sendMessage(Constants.CLOSED_CONNECTION+"Kazy");*/

        mRun = false;

        if (mBufferOut != null) {
            mBufferOut.flush();
            mBufferOut.close();
        }

        mMessageListener = null;
        mBufferIn = null;
        mBufferOut = null;
        mServerMessage = null;
    }

    public void run() {

        mRun = true;

        try {
            //here you must put your computer's IP address.
            InetAddress serverAddr = InetAddress.getByName(SERVER_IP);

            Log.e("TCP Client", "C: Connecting...");

            //create a socket to make the connection with the server
            Socket socket = new Socket(serverAddr, SERVER_PORT);

            try {

                //sends the message to the server
                mBufferOut = new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(socket.getOutputStream())), true);

                //receives the message which the server sends back
                mBufferIn = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
                // send login name
                sendMessage("hi");

                //in this while the client listens for the messages sent by the server
                while (mRun) {

                    mServerMessage = mBufferIn.readLine();

                    if (mServerMessage != null && mMessageListener != null) {
                        //call the method messageReceived from MyActivity class
                        mMessageListener.messageReceived(mServerMessage);
                    }

                }

                Log.e("RESPONSE FROM SERVER", "S: Received Message: '" + mServerMessage + "'");

            } catch (Exception e) {

                Log.e("TCP", "S: Error", e);

            } finally {
                //the socket must be closed. It is not possible to reconnect to this socket
                // after it is closed, which means a new socket instance has to be created.
                socket.close();
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {

            Log.e("TCP", "C: Error", e);

        }
    }

    //Declare the interface. The method messageReceived(String message) will must be implemented in the MyActivity
    //class at on asynckTask doInBackground
    public interface OnMessageReceived {
        public void messageReceived(String message);
   }
}
```

The class where my ConnectTask class is.

```
public class DeviceDetailFragment extends Fragment implements ConnectionInfoListener {

    protected static final int CHOOSE_FILE_RESULT_CODE = 20;
    private View mContentView = null;
    private WifiP2pDevice device;
    private WifiP2pInfo info;
    ProgressDialog progressDialog = null;
    TCPClient mTCPClient;

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        mContentView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.device_detail, null);
        mContentView.findViewById(R.id.btn_connect).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                WifiP2pConfig config = new WifiP2pConfig();
                config.deviceAddress = device.deviceAddress;
                config.wps.setup = WpsInfo.PBC;
                if (progressDialog != null && progressDialog.isShowing()) {
                    progressDialog.dismiss();
                }
                progressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(getActivity(), "Press back to cancel",
                    "Connecting to :" + device.deviceAddress, true, true
    //                        new DialogInterface.OnCancelListener() {
    //
    //                            @Override
    //                            public void onCancel(DialogInterface dialog) {
    //                                ((DeviceActionListener) 
    getActivity()).cancelDisconnect();
    //                            }
    //                        }
                );
                ((DeviceListFragment.DeviceActionListener) getActivity()).connect(config);

            }
        });

        mContentView.findViewById(R.id.btn_disconnect).setOnClickListener(
            new View.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    ((DeviceListFragment.DeviceActionListener) getActivity()).disconnect();
                }
            });

        /*
        mContentView.findViewById(R.id.btn_start_client).setOnClickListener(
            new View.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    // Allow user to pick an image from Gallery or other
                    // registered apps
                    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
                    intent.setType("image/*");
                    startActivityForResult(intent, CHOOSE_FILE_RESULT_CODE);
                }
            });
        */

        return mContentView;
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionInfoAvailable(final WifiP2pInfo info) {
        if (progressDialog != null && progressDialog.isShowing()) {
            progressDialog.dismiss();
        }
        this.info = info;
        this.getView().setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

        // The owner IP is now known.
        TextView view = (TextView) mContentView.findViewById(R.id.group_owner);
        view.setText(getResources().getString(R.string.group_owner_text)
            + ((info.isGroupOwner == true) ? getResources().getString(R.string.yes)
            : getResources().getString(R.string.no)));

        // InetAddress from WifiP2pInfo struct.
        view = (TextView) mContentView.findViewById(R.id.device_info);
        view.setText("Group Owner IP - " + info.groupOwnerAddress.getHostAddress());
        if(info.groupFormed) {
            new ConnectTask().execute("");
            if (mTCPClient != null) {
                 mTCPClient.sendMessage("testing");
            }
            //sends the message to the server
        }

        // After the group negotiation, we assign the group owner as the file
        // server. The file server is single threaded, single connection server
        // socket.
        /*
        if (info.groupFormed && info.isGroupOwner) {
            new FileServerAsyncTask(getActivity(), mContentView.findViewById(R.id.status_text))
                .execute();
        }
        */

        // hide the connect button
        mContentView.findViewById(R.id.btn_connect).setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }

    /**
     * Updates the UI with device data
     *
     * @param device the device to be displayed
     */
    public void showDetails(WifiP2pDevice device) {
        this.device = device;
        this.getView().setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        TextView view = (TextView) mContentView.findViewById(R.id.device_address);
        view.setText(device.deviceAddress);
        view = (TextView) mContentView.findViewById(R.id.device_info);
        view.setText(device.toString());
    }

    /**
     * Clears the UI fields after a disconnect or direct mode disable operation.
     */
    public void resetViews() {
        mContentView.findViewById(R.id.btn_connect).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        TextView view = (TextView) mContentView.findViewById(R.id.device_address);
        view.setText(R.string.empty);
        view = (TextView) mContentView.findViewById(R.id.device_info);
        view.setText(R.string.empty);
        view = (TextView) mContentView.findViewById(R.id.group_owner);
        view.setText(R.string.empty);
        /*
        view = (TextView) mContentView.findViewById(R.id.status_text);
        view.setText(R.string.empty);
        this.getView().setVisibility(View.GONE);
        */
    }

    public class ConnectTask extends AsyncTask<String, String, TCPClient> {

        @Override
        protected TCPClient doInBackground(String... message) {

            //we create a TCPClient object
            mTCPClient = new TCPClient(new TCPClient.OnMessageReceived() {
                @Override
                //here the messageReceived method is implemented
                public void messageReceived(String message) {
                    //this method calls the onProgressUpdate
                    publishProgress(message);
                }
            });
            mTCPClient.run();

            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onProgressUpdate(String... values) {
            super.onProgressUpdate(values);
            //response received from server
            Log.d("test", "response " + values[0]);
            //process server response here....


        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Your client is expecting the server to send a line break after each message. Is it actually sending one? Also note that `PrintWriter.println()` prints a link break that is dependent on the platform it is being called on. What kind of link break is the server actually expecting? You might need to use `print()` instead of `println()` and include the appropriate line break at the end of the `string` being printed.

Comment: @RemyLebeau Thank you for the answer, you are right. The server was not sending a line. Thanks for the edit, english is not my first language so I appreciate it.